# Is searchBar: textDidChange: efficient for low memory devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

```
searchBar: textDidChange:
```

is a great delegate method which greatly improves UX, but is it overkill to use it on low memory devices like iPhone 3G, or original iPhone?

If it is, can you provide me a snippet that checks which iOS device is used, so I can implement `textDidChange:` for newer devices, and leave it off for older.

Comment: Are you trying to target the original iPhone or the iPhone 3G? What version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this method is not overkill.  This method runs smoothly on all releases of iOS hardware and as long as there is not intensive code within that function you should be fine. (ex, blocking code, like writing to files, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

That method was added in iOS 2.0, which was released just a year after the original iPhone was released, and at the same time as the iPhone 3G, so it should be fine to use on those devices.

Comment: They probably didn't add it to do exactly this type of thing. Who knows?

Comment: I don't know what that comment means. What type of thing are you talking about? I also don't know why you think that method uses a lot of memory. But I'm telling you that it's fine to use that method on the iPhone or iPhone 3G.